# Changing language with React Native and django-modeltranslation

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I would like to add option to mobile app to change language. Im using django on backend and RN as mobile. So I installed `django-modeltranslation` and added my model I want to translate. On mobile I display available languages. When user clicks on specific language I would like to get translated data. I have huge problem to create logic how to do it. I'm not asking about code just some hints and idea

EDIT:
For example: I added translation from `django-modeltranslation` to my model (i.e GameTask with field title, description etc). In my `settings.py` I have declared languages ('en','de','uk',etc) and added translations in database (for every field of GameTask, I added title(en), title(de) etc). When I change language in `settings.py`, values on mobile are changing too (so working as intended). So im not storing any translated text in app files, just in database (except of static errors and informations). Now I just want to send info from mobile with chosen language and activate this language on backend to return content in specific language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely make your application multi-language, you need two things.

- Translation system for your app
- Translation system for your api.

First, use a pre-built context api or create your own to support changing language in-app. Something like this: https://medium.com/@ally_20818/multi-language-text-with-react-native-react-context-b76d5677346d

When user changes the language, store the language name or key in async-storage or some other database.

Change the texts in the react-native side based on the selected language.

When you're making a api call, send the selected language too. Get the selected language on api side and return appropriate texts based on language.

**UPDATE:**

Since you're not storing any text on react-native side, you only need to add a picker ([react-native-picker/picker](https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker) is a native picker) and store the selected language key (en, de, uk etc in your case) in a database like `react-native-async-storage`. When you're making api requests with react-native, include an additional header or post data which includes selected language key. And you can get and use that key in your django back-end.